How to close popup when redirect and use query parameter (JS)
I am building a webtool that should be able to call the Strava api. Before being able to create the actual request, the customer should give the authorisation. This is done via an authorise call:
https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=123456&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost/exchange_token&approval_prompt=force&scope=activity:read_all
It consists of a client_id which is linked to my application and a redirect URL. When opening the URL, the user sees a screen where he/she is able to authorise my app. After an approval, he/she got redirected to the redirect url with a query parameter called code=730f5fbb0b7djske9d66e85568a526e4e8sfb2ah. This is the actual authorisation code that should be used when doing new calls.
My question is how to:

Open the authorise link in a popup
Wait for the user to click on the approval button
Close the popup when the client got redirected
Use the code query parameter that was shown in the redirect url in the webtool to make new calls

I already found some JavaScript code to execute step one, but that's all:
  const url = await 'https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=123456&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost/exchange_token&approval_prompt=force&scope=activity:read_all'; 
  const authPopup = window.open(url, "", "popup=true"); 

Step 2 should be done by the customer, but could someone help me with step 3 and 4? Any tips are welcome. I am quite new to JavaScript.

You have to communicate with the opened window using postMessage and onmessage global method.

First step, add the listener to the onmessage of opener window means the script opening the  popup which receives the data sent by our popup via postMessage.
 window.onmessage = ({ data }) => { // data is sent from the popup
     if(data?.type === 'close'){
         window.auth_popup?.close(); // closing the popup STEP #3
         delete window.auth_popup;
         const code = data?.data; // you will get code here STEP #4
         console.log(code);
     }
 }

 function yourfunction { // this probably called when an event occurs
     const windowFeatures = "popup";
     window.auth_popup = window.open(
         "https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=123456&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost/exchange_token&approval_prompt=force&scope=activity:read_all",
         "Auth",
         windowFeatures,
     );
 }


Second most important thing, add some script in the redirect url page to get the code param and sent that code to the opener means the page opened the popup.
 let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search)

 window.opener?.postMessage(// posting a message to the parent window
 { 
     type:"close",
     data: params.get('code')
 }
 );



Note: this script has to be executed from the redirect url page

Thanks for your answer. Small question on bullet point 2: How to make sure this postMessage is added in the redirect url page?
Other question: some clients should still be able to login (for example via Facebook). In this case, the URL will be changed multiple times before going back to the redirect URL. Is your code able to handle this? Because the code param will only be available in the last redirection

I mean add the code in the http://localhost/exchange_token&approval_prompt=force&scope=activity:read_all page

so you can get the code inside the redirect url

Could you  more specific on how to do this? When the page got redirected to the localhost/exchange.... I want the popup to be closed and use the code param in the original webpage that opened the popup. I do not want to open a new url on the original caller/webpage.

you are asking to close the popup when redirected and use the code in the main page instead of redirected url's code. right?

Yes, but only close the popup when this kind of redirection is done: http://localhost/exchange_token&approval_prompt=force&scope=activity:read_all. I do not want to already close the popup when the client is redirected to his/her Facebook login or something

the code does exactly if you place the script inside the redirection page. Are you facing any problem in adding the script?

if you think my code is useful and gave some idea, please upvote, will encourage me :)

I have put all your code together in the JS file that is loaded in my HTML page. Clicking the button opens the popup, I can click 'authorise' on Strava, I got redirected to the localhost URL. But then the popup stays open and no data is send to the original page...
PS: Ill definitely upvote and mark it resolved when I got the solution :)
